# Не работает ajax скрипт

Tags: php, ajax

Вот форма

```
<form action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <p><input type="text" name="product-title" placeholder="Название товара"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Укажите 0 если цена договорная"></p>
    <p><textarea name="product-description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></p>
    <?


    $i = 0;
    $categories = R::find('categories');
    echo "<p><select name='categorie' id='categorie'>";
    foreach ($categories as $categorie) 
        {
            echo "<option value='$i'>" . $categorie['title'] . "</option>";
            $i++;
        }
    echo "</select>";


    $cat = $_GET['cat'];
    $filters = R::find('filters', 'categorie = ?', array($cat));

    echo "<p><select name='filter' id='filter'>";
    echo "</select>";

    ?>
</form>
```

Вот сам скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#categorie').change(function() {
        var categorieId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'filter.php',
                data: 'cat=' + categorieId,
                succes: function(html){
                    $('#filter').html(html);
                }
            })
    });
});
```

Вот файл filter.php

```
<?

require('libs/connection.php');
echo $_POST['filter'];
$filters = R::find('filters', 'categorie = ?', array($_POST['categorie']));


    foreach ($filters as $filter) 
    {
        echo "<option value=" .$filter['id']. ">" . $filter['title'] . "</option>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: http запрос уходит?

Answer (score 0):

В javascript-e Вы назвали отправляемое значение `cat`:

```
$filters = R::find('filters', 'categorie = ?', array($_POST['cat']));
```

*Совет дня: называйте одну и ту же вещь одним и тем же именем.*